# What is the point of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am looking at some code, and I've come across this thing called ArrayLists? What exactly is the point of using ArrayLists as oppose to regular lists? And if you look at the code, before the methods names you have `<T> ArrayList<T>`. Is it because these are `ArrayLists`? And why the `<T>`?

```
class MergeAlgorithm{

    //ArrayLists
    <T> ArrayList<T> merge(ArrayList<T> list1, ArrayList<T> list2, 
            Comparator<T> comp, ArrayList<T> acc){
        if(list1.isEmpty())
            return append(acc, list2);
        else if(list2.isEmpty())
            return append(acc, list1);
        else if(comp.compare(list1.get(0), list2.get(0)) <= 0){
            acc.add(list1.get(0));
            list1.remove(0);
            return merge(list1, list2, comp, acc);
        }
        else{
            acc.add(list2.get(0));
            list2.remove(0);
            return merge(list1, list2, comp, acc);
        }



    }



<T> ArrayList<T> append(ArrayList<T> list1, ArrayList<T> list2){
    for (T t: list2){
        list1.add(t);
    }
    return list1;
}
}


class CharComp implements Comparator<Character>{
    public int compare(Character c1, Character c2){
        return c1.compareTo(c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is just an implementation of the `List` interface; as such, it can be viewed as a "regular List" since it is the most used implementation of this interface (`List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();`)

Comment: You need to learn about Java generics.  You have <T> so you can have Lists of any kind of object with strong type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the point of using ArrayLists as oppose to regular lists?

It depends on what you mean by a "regular list".

- If you mean `java.util.List`, then the point is that you cannot create an instance of that `List` type ... because it is an `interface` not a `class`.
- If you mean some other list class such as `java.util.LinkedList` ... then you need to realize that each of the different list classes have their own behavioural / performance characteristics.  For example:

  - The `LinkedList` has fast insertion at the start of the list, but a slow `get(int)` operation compared to `ArrayList`
  - The `ArrayList` class has fast `get`, and uses less memory on average<sup>1</sup> than an equivalent `LinkedList`.

---

> And if you look at the code, before the methods names you have `<T> ArrayList<T>`. Is it because these are `ArrayLists`? And why the `<T>`

The `<T>` denotes a type parameter of the generic `merge` and `append` methods.  Read the Java Tutorial section on [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) ... and then you should be able to understand what this code is saying.

No, it is not *"because these are `ArrayLists`"*.  You'd need to use the a generic type parameter for other list classes as well.  The `List` interface and all of the standard list classes are generic types.

---

<sup>1 - The space usage of `ArrayList` is a bit rubbery, because it depends on the sequence of operations used to get to the list whose space usage you are measuring.  But an optimal `ArrayList` occupies *much* less space than a `LinkedList` with the same elements.  And this is true for *typical* use-cases as well.</sup>